# Style the title

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

```
 def multiple_dfs(file_name, sheet, *args):
        """
        Put multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet
        """

        row=2
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

        df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=0, header=None, \
                 index=False)
```

I would like to resize and bold `Title` from this code with `pandas` (or with `openpyxl` if it is not possible with `pandas`). Is there a way to do it accurately and "pythonically"?

I know we could use http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html, but I don't know how to use it with my code.

### UPDATE

According to @AndyHayden, normally the following code should bold the title, but that seems to not working.

```
import pandas as pd
import io, os, openpyxl

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import (PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font)

def multiple_dfs(sheet):

    row=2
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

    df = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                       'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=0, header=None, \
                 index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
        ws.append(r)

    title = ws["A1"]; title.font = Font(bold=True)
    wb.save("testing.xlsx")                

    writer.save()
    writer.close()

multiple_dfs('aaa')
```

The title is never showed up in bold. How could I fix that?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: The to_excel and the wb.save are going to confuse each other, if you're styling I recommend not doing the to_excel but INSTEAD the dataframe_to_rows snippet.

Comment: @AndyHayden It's been awhile I am working on that. Could you adapt my code so that it works? It is very hard for me, because all my REAL code is working with `pandas` and `to_excel`.

Answer (score 1):

The [openpyxl docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html#working-with-pandas-dataframes) offer a neat way to do this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

for cell in ws['A'] + ws[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

wb.save("pandas_openpyxl.xlsx")
```

---

Note: That if you are doing some other inserting beforehand (like you suggest in your previous question, you'll have to use a different row number.

Comment: Suppose that `file_name` is called `NHL_databases.xlsx`. Could you adapt your code with that.

Comment: @J.Doe replace pandas_openpyxl.xlsx with NHL_databases.xlsx ?

Comment: Ok, that is fine, but why my title is not bold? Are you able to fix it or just fit my question code with you answer code?

Comment: @J.Doe so, you can do something like `title = ws["A1"]; title.font = Font(bold=True)`.

Comment: I am not sure how it works... Sorry I've started programming in python early.